# Creating coverage report through nose test

Tags: python-2.7, nose

when I am trying to generate coverage report through nosetests. I am getting the warning message Module is never imported

my test are running but it's not able to cover report

PYTHONPATH=sample nosetests --with-xunit --verbose --cover-branches --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=sample --cover-html

for example:

XML: nosetests.xml
Coverage.py warning: Module sample/* was never imported.

Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.

Name                              Stmts   Miss      Cover   Missing

---

sample.core                           1      1     0.000%   1

sample.helpers                      111    111     0.000%   12-314

sample.conf                          13     13     0.000%   13-48

---

TOTAL                               125    125     0.000%

---

Ran 31 tests in 10.357s

OK

Comment: have you solved this problem?